# How to detect Lightbox (ie, "PrettyPhoto") iFrame focus

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I need to perform certain jQuery actions each time the focus changes from PrettyPhoto frame to the next.

Does anyone know what the HMTL & JS coding would look like to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/ says something about changepicturecallback is that what you serach for? Or maybe I miss understand you

Comment: Thanks @SimonEdström. Yes, I have been trying to get `changepicturecallback` and many, many other jQuery commands to work over the past 2-3 days and had no success until I just happened to try what I spell out in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST placed your .js file immediately before the closing  tag, and not in the common  tag section. I hope my 2-3 days of spinning my wheels helps someone out! Good luck.

Comment: This is the  higher-level answer. I'll come back in 2 days to accept this as the answer unless someone else helps out by selecting it first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Detect focus for one item.

```
$('#iFrameId').bind('focus',function(event){
   //DO SOMETHING AS A REACTION TO THE FOCUS
});
```

Detect focus on all images in the photo container might be something like this:

```
$('#Photos img').bind('focus',function(event){
         //DO SOMETHING AS A REACTION TO THE FOCUS
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JoshSiok. I have been at this for 2-3 days now. See my answer.